# Can you use assistance actions in combat?

Tags: combat, fate, dresden-files, aspects, helping

I checked the teamwork rules (YS P. 208) and it seems like it can be used in combat based on the text, but I want to be sure. So I was wondering:

1. Can teamwork actions be used in combat to create taggable aspects?
2. If so, is the target number still one or two less like on page 208 of YS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**To answer the first part of your question- Yes.**

Supporting text - *from (YS208)*

> You can also use maneuvers (**even outside of conflict**) to
>   coordinate on an action with several people.

*Emphasis mine.*  That point would not be relevant if you couldn't use it in combat.

**As far as the second part of your question,** the answer is really going to depend on what the characters are doing to inform the teamwork.  The first thing to remember is that in most cases, making the maneuver is taking the place of the character's action for the round, in order to get an advantage to the one roll.  Therefore this sort of sacrificial play should be rewarded by that reduction in difficulty.  However, some applications of maneuvers are not intrinsically less difficult just because it is not a direct maneuver against the character.

**A couple of examples:**

> Karrin and Harry have cornered a Black Court Vampire in a warehouse
>   and are trying to put him down.
>
> Karrin tries to drive the vampire back so that Harry can get the room
>   to take him out, by laying down suppressive fire.  The target for that
>   maneuver would be the vampire's athletics skill, with no bonus to that
>   roll.
>
> Finding that the vampire is too fast for her to pin down, Karrin
>   unloads on one of the liquor crates to spread the liquor on the ground
>   to enhance the effects of Harry's flammable personality.  Though the
>   vampire would have the possibility of getting out of the way of the
>   liquor, it would be conceivable that this roll would be lessened in
>   difficulty because of the nature of the target.

**In the end, whether you get the reduction in difficulty should be decided by the GM and informed by the player's actions and the narrative.**